# Gridview inside Update panel PageIndex not maintained on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview inside update panel and a button on whose click gridview is binded.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelPrjSumm" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProjectionSummary" runat="server"           
         AutoGenerateColumns="true"  AllowPaging="true" PageSize="18" 
         OnPageIndexChanging="gvProjectionSummary_PageIndexChanging"
         OnRowDataBound="gvProjectionSummary_RowDataBound" PagerSettings-     
         Mode="Numeric" >
        </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChange" OnClick="btnChange_Click"  
  Text="Change" />
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click on Change button ,  gridview is rebinded but page index number is reset to 1 irrespective of on which page I was when button was clicked.

**1** 2 3 4

How to maintain page number while using this Update panel control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the page number in `ViewState` and update it just before you rebind it. just before rebinding the `GridView` assign the page number from the `ViewState`

Comment: Superbbb Adil bhaijaan !! I was already doing it using Session variable but doing mistake that I was assigning pageIndex property after BindGrid() instead of **BEFORE** . Solves my problem .

Comment: You are welcome bro, I would suggest to use ViewState instead of session as grid context is page not pages.

Answer (score 0):

****try this.... use  property of updatepanel****

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelPrjSumm" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvProjectionSummary" />
        </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProjectionSummary" runat="server"           
         AutoGenerateColumns="true"  AllowPaging="true" PageSize="18" 
         OnPageIndexChanging="gvProjectionSummary_PageIndexChanging"
         OnRowDataBound="gvProjectionSummary_RowDataBound" PagerSettings-     
         Mode="Numeric" >
        </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChange" OnClick="btnChange_Click"  
  Text="Change" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```